# how to open a dynamic web form from a link with selenium

Tags: selenium, web

**Hi everybody**

I'd like to test a dynamic form in a web page with Selenium. Actually, i need to click on a link to get the form and the form is located on the same page so..the form just comes behind the link.

The test has to start when i hit a link and Selenium drop an error which says that the Element id is not found. Check this out : http://www.thalys.com/be/fr/aide#contacts. There i have to hit the Reclamation link and when i try to test i have : [error] Element id=reclamation not found and the test is stoped.

Do you know what kind of command i have to use? Thank you

Comment: I just found why it was bugging. Actually Selenium was bugging...i was using the click command and now it works

Answer (score 0):

From the formulated question I see the simpliest way is to use driver get(url). e.g.

```
String url= "http://www.thalys.com/be/fr/aide#contacts"
 @Before
    public void openFirefox() throws IOException {


        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get(url);
    }
```

Have you tried this approach?